# Xcode 5 - -bundle_loader can only be used with -bundle XCTest

Tags: xcode, linker-errors, xcode5

I am working on unit tests with XCTest and Xcode 5. Everything was working just fine, but then a colleague made a push, and it seems to have broken it.

I have done the following:

> BUNDLE_LOADER = $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/app name.app/app
>
> TEST_HOST = $(BUNDLE_LOADER)

and I have played around with the build paths endlessly.

Here is the error I am getting, which is tied to a Linker-O error.

> -bundle_loader can only be used with -bundle

Anyone know how to fix this?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The Mach-O Linker flag in the test target was set to "executable" instead of "bundle".

Comment: Can you please specify where that linker flag can be found?

Comment: Sure, go to the Test Target build settings, and then search for Mach-O or Linker, and you should see it as "Mach-O Linker".

Comment: Thank you! You saved me a ton of headache! I'd +2 if I could!

Comment: You are a scholar. Thank you. I've been looking for this solution for far too long. @Siriss