# iOS project gives error "-bundle_loader can only be used with -bundle" in Apple Mach-O Linker error

Tags: ios, objective-c, linker-errors

i am using xcode 6.0 and deployment target 7.0.
it gives error linker error. please give me solution.i am sick of it.
thanks in advance

Text of clang error:

`"-bundle_loader can only be used with -bundle"`

[image: Screenshot of linker errors]

Comment: are u using any flag?

Comment: are you using any sdk or any framework ??

Comment: Posting screenshots is not very useful in this case. Information about which target are you building, if you're using CocoaPods and the error message in text form helps a lot to solve your issue

Comment: possible duplicate of [Xcode 5 - -bundle\_loader can only be used with -bundle XCTest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321771/xcode-5-bundle-loader-can-only-be-used-with-bundle-xctest)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're building your target test, then [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19321771/xcode-5-bundle-loader-can-only-be-used-with-bundle-xctest) should help you.

> go to the Test Target build settings, and then search for "Mach-O" or "Linker", and you should see it as "Mach-O Linker", Mach-O Linker flag in the test target was set to "executable" instead of "bundle".

Linker flag as of Xcode 6 is called `Mach-O Type`

Comment: do i need to set flag of "other linker flag" in Test Target build settings?

Comment: Search for "Mach-O Type"